# normalize.css not being found by asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bower

I get the error `couldn't find file 'normalize.css' with type 'text/css'`. I am using bower to manage my css/js dependencies and should have everything set up correctly, so I'm not sure why rails is telling me it can't find the file ...

```
> app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/*
 *= require normalize.css
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

> config.application.rb
...
module RailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    # Add Bower components to assets pipeline
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
  end
end

> .bowerrc
{
  "directory":"vendor/assets/bower_components"
}
```

And of course I have installed normalize.css using `bower install --save normalize.css`.

For a temporary workaround I just downloaded and placed `normalize.css` in my `vendor/assets/stylesheets` folder and used `*= require normalize` in `application.css`. The `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')` line doesn't seem to make a difference.